# Why the `singleton` methods can't be defined on `Fixnum`,`Bignum`,`Float`,`Symbol` class objects, but ` FalseClass` and `TrueClass` can have?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

Why the `singleton` methods can't be defined on `Fixnum`,`Bignum`,`Float`,`Symbol` class objects, but `FalseClass` and `TrueClass` can have?

```
C:\>ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24) [i386-mingw32]

C:\>irb --simple-prompt
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
11111111111.class
#=> Bignum
class << 11111111111 ; end
#TypeError: can't define singleton
#        from (irb):2
#        from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

1111.class
#=> Fixnum
class << 1111 ; end
#TypeError: can't define singleton
#       from (irb):4
#       from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

11.11.class
#=> Float
class << 11.11 ; end
#TypeError: can't define singleton
#       from (irb):6
#       from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

:name.class
#=> Symbol
class << :name ; end
#TypeError: can't define singleton
#       from (irb):8
#       from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Don't you mean "instance objects", not "class objects"? BTW, the instance object of `NilClass` also allows singleton objects.

Answer (score 7):

As the [Ruby Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html) say:

> There is effectively only one Fixnum object instance for any given integer value, so, for example, you cannot add a singleton method to a Fixnum.

The same is true for `Bignum`, `Float` and `Symbol`

Comment: But why not for `false`, `true` or `nil`?

Comment: This is completely wrong: `big_fix = 4611686018427387903; big_fix.class #=> Fixnum; big1 = big_fix+1; big1.class #=> Bignum; big2 = big_fix+1; big1.object_id == big2.object_id #=> false` so there can be **many** Bignums with the same value but different references.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD This was not true of Bignums, as you have shown, but it was true of Fixnums, as the doc says. Ruby has done away with the distinction, so now they are all Integers. In the present arrangement, Integer values with up to 19 numerals always have the same object id, while larger ones do not.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Fixnum.html):

*There is effectively only one Fixnum object instance for any given integer value, so, for example, you cannot add a singleton method to a Fixnum.*

That would apply to other primitive numeric types and Symbol.

Answer (score 1):

The defining feature of a [`Singleton` class](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html) is: It only has **one instance**.

- There is only one instance of `FalseClass`: `false`.
- There is only one instance of `TrueClass`: `true`.
- There is only one instance of `NilClass`: `nil`.

This is *not the same thing* as, for example, the `Float` and `Symbol` classes; these are *not* Singletons.

Whilst it is true that there is only one instance of these classes *for a given value*:

```
3.14159.object_id #=> 20565057194439538
3.14159.object_id #=> 20565057194439538
3.14159.object_id #=> 20565057194439538
:hello.object_id  #=> 3551708
:hello.object_id  #=> 3551708
:hello.object_id  #=> 3551708
```

Unlike, for example, the `String` class which does not have this property:

```
"test".object_id #=> 34347120
"test".object_id #=> 34388680
"test".object_id #=> 22397760
```

Remember that this is *not* the definition of a Singleton. `:foo` and `:bar` are two *different* instances of `Symbol`.

This is why the `singleton` methods can be defined on `TrueClass`, `FlaseClass` and `NilClass` but not, for example, on `Symbol`.